# MongoDB : mongoose findbyidandupdate condition not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update an array in a document where array is array of user object.

The problem is i don't want to add duplicates in this array ( not the same user more than one time).

what i do :

```
const updatedTopic = await Topic.findByIdAndUpdate(
    // @ts-ignore
    { _id: id, 'votes.user': { $ne: req.user?._id.valueOf() } },
    // @ts-ignore
    { $push: { votes: { year, comment, user: req.user } } },
    { new: true }
  );
```

But this isn't working as you can see below :

```
  {
  "name": "Argomento 1",
  "exam": {
    "$oid": "62b71b9dcaf3e92ac568c729"
  },
  "slug": "argomento-1",
  "user": {
    "$oid": "62534e5798a11bcba35464f6"
  },
  "votes": [
    {
      "year": 2022,
      "comment": "",
      "user": {
        "$oid": "62b22fd314c40b9067f84cc2"  -> same user
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62b8bbcf876b2d27570fdf86"
      }
    },
    {
      "year": 2022,
      "comment": "",
      "user": {
        "$oid": "62b22fd314c40b9067f84cc2"  -> same user
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62b8bbd5876b2d27570fdf89"
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656168790097"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656274729989"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: convert this `req.user?._id.valueOf()` into ObjectId and try

Comment: @CharchitKapoor What you mean by that ? without .valueOf() i guess it is already object it and i tried with it

Comment: @CharchitKapoor console.log(req.user._id) is new ObjectId("62b22fd314c40b9067f84cc2")

Comment: Ok, if it's already ObjectId, then it's fine, similarly for id right?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor i think so, as it finds the document and updates it, only 'votes.user': { $ne: req.user?._id.valueOf() } this condition isn't working as it create duplicates

Comment: You can try this for matching document with the "not the existing user" condition: `{ votes: { $not: { $elemMatch: { user: <some value> } } } }`.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for your answer but solved by changing `findByIdAndUpdate` to `findOneAndUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but changing `findByIdAndUpdate` to `findOneAndUpdate` works fine.

Probably `findByIdAndUpdate` checks only the id condition.